# How to create this cracked leather texture effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

The *Instagram* logo pulls off this effect nicely to create a cracked brown-leather look.  How can I create this texture? (regardless of the color)

*Instagram* logo:

[image: Instagram logo image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the most obvious answers are the hardest to realize... get a photo of brown leather and overlay it to create the texture.

Comment: thanks, that's a great answer. In your opinion, is this how Instagram achieved this effect?

Comment: probably for that middle section. the rest could have been with a leather overlay and then applying the grain filter or skipping the leather overlay and just using the grain filter. But in that middle part where it looks the most like leather I would say yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the better to use Patters from blending option. You can download lot of leather patters which has nice bump depth and can apply on any color will give a nice leather effect .

One more way is You can use filter> textures ( refer : http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/textures-patterns/creating-an-awesome-leather-texture-in-77-seconds-with-photoshop.19373.html) even this gives you the required output.